# How can I prevent "spam" user registrations?

Tags: users

We recently launched our first site with front end user registration and we are getting a lot (not a ton, like 5 a day) spam registrations. See here:

[image: Spam accounts]

Im trying to find a way to cut down on these without doing something like a captcha but maybe thats my only option?

Comment: Hey, we have some of those same users =).  Are you just using native Craft login functionality or any plugins to allow social sign on?  I've been resisting implementing a solution to our problem while I try to figure out where these spam users are coming from as they don't seem to trigger the expected Craft events.

Comment: yea it just native user registration, no plugin involved yet.  It seemed odd to me as well that most are from the same source.  Anyways looks like i'll need to add a plug of some sort or at least turn auto activation back off

Answer (score 4):

**Plugins:**

- [**Snaptcha**](http://www.putyourlightson.net/craft-cms-plugins) (private beta)
  Works with the User Registration Form, Contact Form Plugin and Sprout Forms Plugin
- [**Invisible Captcha**](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/invisible-captcha) (private beta)

.

**Config:**

If you don't mind having a few spam-users in your list. Just add [`purgePendingUsersDuration`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#purgePendingUsersDuration) to your config.

This will purge all users which haven't been activated for x time.

Comment: It would be pretty slick if someone made a honeypot plugin as well.

Comment: @BryanRedeagle 'Invisible Captcha' has a Honeypot option: http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/invisible-captcha/docs/getting-started/introduction#invisible-captcha-methods-available